# Best way of continually logging location

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm looking for the best way to continually monitor the location of an Android device, while using the lowest amount of battery power. My project is basically a phone tracking service, with phone call / sms logging, and location tracking. There is a web interface, which would eventually allow a person to change settings (such as location update interval, so if it was stolen they could track it more effectively), but as standard it should update the location every 30-60 minutes.

I was thinking of using a Service, but would it be better to start a service, request location updates, and then finish? Or some other method?

Cheers

Comment: You can requestLocationUpdate at specified interval in requestLocationUpdated API.

Answer (score 0):

> but would it be better to start a service, request location updates, and then finish?

Yes, simply so you do not need to keep a service around all the time. However, it's a bit more complicated than that:

- you might never get a fix (e.g., the phone is underground and cannot get GPS signals)
- you need to keep the service around until you get a fix or until some timeout occurs
- you have to worry about the device falling asleep while all this is going on

I have a [`LocationPoller`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) component that handles most of that.